# Lost files on my ubuntu cloud

Tags: ubuntu-one, files

My folder on the cloud has disappeared is there a way to get it back?

Answer (score 3):

Right now, the best way to recover a deleted folder is to contact Ubuntu One support at https://one.ubuntu.com/support/contact.