# Ubuntu One lost most of my files!

Tags: ubuntu-one

I keep the source code of my projects in my Ubuntu One as a back up.

In the past it worked and I never had any problems. I had to change the hard disk of my laptop so I installed a fresh Ubuntu 12.10 on the new drive.

Ubuntu One downloaded my files the first time I connected. But when I checked on my projects, almost all of my C++ source code files were missing!!! I tried to check if I still had them on Ubuntu One by accessing from the web but nothing... my work is lost forever.

I don't know who to ask for help? Is there a way to get back my precious files?
Honestly I can't trust this service any more, I'm very disappointed.

#### Edit:

Thank God I found a back up in one of my external hard disks. I won't trust Ubuntu One any more, it's buggy and quite slow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lost files on my ubuntu cloud](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36159/lost-files-on-my-ubuntu-cloud)

Comment: If you contact the support and post here a solution you'll help to improve the Ubuntu One service.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem once. I think the only solution is to request a data recovery. (At least it was the only one I found!)
You can contact the support team:

https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/

Explain to them the same situation. One of the admin. can recover most of your files.

I don't know why this happen, but is a huge bug they should fix soon.

Take care,
Seb.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your folder should show the option "Restore lost files" or something like this. I've never used this service, but it seems to be a solution. Try it.

Comment: I just tried, nothing. It said "checking for backup..." and then "couldn't find any backup"!

Comment: Well, so you should follow the link that Jacob Johan Edwards posted and contact Ubuntu One support.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where is the folder one should "right click" on? In the Ubuntu One folder on your PC or on the Ubuntu One web site?

Comment: In the Ubuntu One folder on your PC, or any other folder you've set as shared in Ubuntu One.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in on the web browser, not the app, and you will find some of them, and an option to "recover deleted files" although you might only find files but the folders are empty. It seems the best way to save is t save files that are not inside folders. I was vexed to fine all my folders with a tick to show they have been synced only to find that they are empty!!!

Answer (score 0):

by the way i discovered that you can still get the files by using the search button above your home button on the desktop. Just type the name of file or folder and try the different folders. you might get most of them, although I don't know where they are hidden.